# FileChannel.open() vs RandomAccessFile in Jdk 7

Tags: java, io, nio

I would like to know the difference between the following:

```
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open();
RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile("RandomFile", "rw");
```

Since Java 7 the class `FileChannel` implements `SeekableByteChannel` therefore has all it needs in order to randomly access the file.

Can we say that the 2 are totally the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileChannel` has many more features since it is also `GatheringByteChannel`, `InterruptibleChannel`, `ScatteringByteChannel`. Besides it can lock files, transfer files, work with direct byte buffers, see API

Comment: So we can say that RandomAccessFile has been totally overcome by FileChannel (now that implements SeekableByteChannel)?